# MAMP permissions issue on Google Drive File System

Tags: apache, mamp

I have recently installed Google Drive File System (Google's new Backup and Sync) on my Mac. It runs on `/Volumes/GoogleDrive/`

Looking to move all my local `/dev/` to `/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My\ Drive/dev/` to keep everything in sync in the cloud. So far so good.

Apache on MAMP won't recognize /Volumes/GoogleDrive/

```
[Wed Dec 20 14:22:38 2017] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Volumes/GoogleDrive
```

..so I created a symlink on the local drive hoping this would work. I get a 403 error now (Forbidden).

```
[Wed Dec 20 14:43:13 2017] [error] [client ::1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /Users/sergiupoenaru/Documents/dev
```

One more thing I did was noticing the permissions are 700 and can't change them to anything else. Read somewhere on the web that you can't chmod a NTFS drive.

Any tips on either how to set the proper permissions or a workaround?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, I have upgraded to the latest MAMP and using this within the httpd.conf

<Directory "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/dev/">

Seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Upon upgrading to the latest MAMP, I could use the following PATH successfully:

```
<Directory "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/dev/">
```